# How much feces does it take to tame dung beetles?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have found a dung beetle and knocked it out by mistake. It said its torpor was at 126/200 and I stayed there for around 20 minutes, but it never went down. I left the cave because all of my feces was about to despawn. I will go back at some point soon as I have not played ark in about a day because I was discouraged due to losing a pteridan and a pig. About how much feces and how long will it take to tame a dung beetle, assuming it's level 30?

Comment: I always use dododex.com to find out taming times / materials I've had good luck with it http://www.dododex.com/taming/dungbeetle/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dung Beetle's wikia page](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dung_Beetle) here is the breakdown of what it will take to tame a **level 30** Dung Beetle:

- If you are using [Large Animal Feces](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Large_Animal_Feces), it will take **6** pieces, on **3:00** minute intervals, for a total time of **15:00**.
- If you are using [Medium Animal Feces](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Medium_Animal_Feces), it will take **8** pieces, on a **1:54** minute interval, for a total time of **13:20**.
- If you are using [Spoiled Meat](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Spoiled_Meat), it will take **12** pieces, on a **3:38** minute interval, for a total time of **40:00**.
- If you are using [Small Animal Feces](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Small_Animal_Feces), it will take **16** pieces, on a **0:53** minute interval, for a total time of **13:20**.
- If you are using [Human Feces](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Human_Feces), it will take **20** pieces, on a **0:42** minute interval, for a total time of **13:20**.
- If you are using [Raw Meat](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Raw_Meat), it will take **80** pieces, on a **1:00** minute interval, for a total time of **1:20:00**.
- If you are using [Raw Fish Meat](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Raw_Fish_Meat), it will take **200** pieces, on a **0:30** minute interval, for a total time of **1:40:00**.

Comment: i will try this later and if it works i will check the answer as accurate, thank you kind fellow. Good hunting!